# Other word for an empty promise (that is likely not to be held)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm not exactly sure how to word my questions properly, but here it is: Say I receive a reply from customer support such as: "We will take your concern very seriously"
But I get the feeling that this is just a generic reply without an actual possibility of the promise being fulfilled.

What do you call such a statement?

---

Wow, and I feared I asked a poor question. I had never dreamed of getting so much feedback, which is what makes accepting an answer so much more difficult (which is further complicated by not being a native speaker). Thanks to everyone for all the replies! I think I'll go with jwpat7's answer because it lists multiple possibilities along with explanations.

Comment: In italian there is the expression "promessa di marinaio" (sailor's promise) to denote a promise devoid of real commitment. The idea is that sailors are traveling around the world, changing port very often and so they can say anything (promise a young girl to marry her, for instance?) without fear of having to oblige.

Comment: **Often the answer is in the question,** for example me as programmer, I added a `static` "**empty**" named `method` in my `Promise` named `class` with the `doc-comment`: "Creates a permanent, never fulfilled nor rejected Promise. ... And under other, this is useful if you `intent` to call `fulfill(...)` or `reject(...)` manually later."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Smarmy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smarmy)* is a possibility; it means "Falsely earnest, smug, or ingratiating."  Also *[weaselly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weasel)*, in sense "A devious or sneaky person or animal", may apply.  An uncommon word that might be relevant is *[fugacious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fugacious)*, "Fleeting, fading quickly, transient", if you expect support to just forget the issue immediately.

More along the line of "empty promise" are words as found in a [clique of *illusory* synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/acliq?r=12010818_1326044479_253665880): *chimerical, fancied, fanciful, fantastic, fictitious, illusory, imaginary, unreal*, and similarly for *fictive* and [perhaps](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/acliq?r=12010818_1326044388_444605412) for *[tenuous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenuous)*, "thin in substance or consistency".

Empty promises in the sense of "say what they want to hear" often are called *[blandishments](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blandishment)*, which is defined as "flattering speech or actions designed to persuade or influence."

Empty promises may also be *evasions, lies, [sophistry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophistry)*. Among the senses of the latter are "an argument that seems plausible, but is fallacious or misleading, especially one devised deliberately to be so"; "the art of using deceptive speech or writing"; and "cunning or trickery".

Answer (score 38):

I would describe such a reply as *[perfunctory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perfunctory)*:

> 1. performed merely as a routine duty; hasty and superficial: *perfunctory courtesy*.
> 2. lacking interest, care, or enthusiasm; indifferent or apathetic

Answer (score 19):

You might say "lip service".

"Verbal expression of agreement or allegiance, unsupported by real conviction or action; "

Comment: Also "hollow promise", but lip service is better

Answer (score 16):

I call it a [*lie*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lie).

Answer (score 10):

A generic reply of this sort is what's known as a *[pro forma](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pro%20forma) statement*:

**pro forma**, *adj.* : Done as a formality; perfunctory. [AHED]

Answer (score 8):

- placating
- boilerplate

**Onomatomaniak** answered “Perfunctory”, and that is dead-on.

- trite
- patronizing
- mollify/pacify

(Just for some more ideas.)

Answer (score 6):

Another term is "pie-crust promise".  Easily made, easily broken.

Comment: That's one I haven't heard before, and the imagery is great. I'll try to incorporate that into my personal vocabulary.

Comment: Excellent imagery, but it sounds somewhat contrived. I'd love to use it, but would rather not have to explain it upon every use.

Comment: You'd only have to explain to people who haven't seen Mary Poppins

Answer (score 5):

What about [nugatory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nugatory) or [jejune](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jejune)?

Answer (score 5):

Let me throw in a technical term here:

**lie** - "2. An intentionally false statement."

Answer (score 5):

Insincere              ......       ......     .......

Answer (score 1):

How about calling the statement [*apathetic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathetic)? It seems to fit the bill quite nicely — "having little or no interest" especially in following up with your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I would brand certain such statements as ***falsehoods***.